# shortcut.TargetPath with space in folder name

Tags: vbscript

Here I have VBScript

```
Dim FileName
FileName = "Shortcut"
Set shortcut = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CreateShortcut(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & + "\" + FileName + ".lnk")
shortcut.Description = "shortcut To a shared folder"
shortcut.TargetPath = "\\server\shared"
shortcut.Save
```

If I have folder named "Shared Folder" (with space in it) , how shall I modify this script to make it work ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the StackOverflow community likes to see evidence of some effort on the part of the person asking the question. In other words, what have you tried that did not work?

That said, the following works for me:

```
shortcut.TargetPath = "\\server\Shared Folder"
```